# BeautifulSoup find div with id and class by one request

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm new in Python.

```
some_soup = BeautifulSoup('<div class="some_class"></div><div id="some_id"></div>')
```

Can i just do something like that:

```
some_soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'some_class', 'id': 'some_id'})
```

instead

```
some_soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'some_class'})
some_soup.findAll('div', {'id': 'some_id'})
```

?
The idea is i need to find certain DIV's with a particular name of "class" and "id" in one expression.
Does BeautifulSoup supports such implementation?

Comment: You can use a function for the filter: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function

Answer (score 1):

*Since an id should be unique, there won't be any need for some_soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'some_class'}) and you can just do some_soup.find(id='some_id')*

**Edit:** At first I thought you just want to get that `div` with some `id`. If you want to get all blocks with a certain class or certain id, You can use filters to achieve what you are looking for:

```
def class_or_id_filter(tag):
    print tag, (tag['id'] if tag.has_attr('id') else 'none')
    return (tag.has_attr('class') and 'some_class' in tag['class']) or (tag.has_attr('id') and tag['id'] == 'some_id')

some_soup.findAll(class_or_id_filter)
```

Comment: Well, in that way it finds just one DIV with "id", but i need to find 'class' and 'id' in one instance.
In other words it should return both of DIV-s.

Comment: Why don't you two searches and append it to a list and iterate over it and do your magic?

Comment: I did :)
But i thought there's a better way to do it using BeautifulSoup's API.

Comment: Thanks a lot @SAM. Not exactly what i need unfortunately. It returns just one concurrence instead of both of them. I'm afraid to think what will happen if there will be a few DIV's with same classes or id's..
I repeat - The idea is i need to find certain DIV's with a particular name of "class" and "id" in one expression.
As RvdK said, it's better to double search and append lists since there's no BeautifulSoup's built in way to do that.